# Let $f : A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$, what does mean that $f$ is a submersion?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I am trying to answer the following question:

Let $M_a := \{ (x^1,\ldots,x^n,x^{n+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : (x^1)^2 + \cdots +(x^n)^2 - (x^{n+1})^2 = a\}$. For which values of $a$, $M_a$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}?$

I have to use the regular value theorem, but I think I don't know in fact how to do it... I thought the following:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:
$f(x^1,\ldots,x^{n+1}) = (x^1)^2 + \cdots+ (x^n)^2 - (x^{n+1})^2.$ Then if $f$ has constant rank, then every set level is a manifold... How to relate this with $a$? I am not seeing the connection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ has constant rank, you have a submersion and $a$ does not matter. But it is not the case (as noticed by Tsemo Aristide):
$$\nabla f(x^1,...,x^{n+1})=(2x^1,...,2x^n,-2x^{n+1}).$$
Therefore, $(0,...,0)$ is not a regular point.

In the theorem, the dependence of the point $a$ appears when you need to check regularity (in this case): $M_a$ is a submanifold if $\nabla f(x)$ is non-zero **for all $x\in M_a$**. So, if you change $a$, you change the points where you have to check the condition on the gradient/differential.

Note that this argument guarantee that $M_a$ is a submanifold for $a\neq 0$.

Comment: thank you! In fact yesterday I realized that once the counter-domain is $\mathbb{R}$ then is necessary and sufficient for $f$ being a submersion that $df \neq 0.$ The $x^1 = \ldots = x^{n+1} = 0$ is the only critical point. So the claim holds for all $a \neq 0.$

Answer (score -2):

You have to compute $df =2x_1dx_1+...2x_ndx_n -2x_{n+1}dx_{n+1}$. Let $a$ be a non zero real. for every $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in f^{-1}(a)$, there exists $i$ such that $x_i\neq 0$. Let $e_i$ be the vector of $R^{n+1}$ whose $i$-coordinate is $1$ and its other coordinates are $0$.  $df_x(0,..,0,1,0..)=x_i\neq 0$. Thus $df_x$ is surjective, and $f^{-1}(a)$ is a manifold.

If $a=0$, $0_{n+1}$ the vector of $R^{n+1}$ whose coordinates are $0$ is in $f^{-1}(0)$. $df_{o_{n+1}}=0$. Thus the tangent space of $f^{-1}(0)$ is not defined at $0_{n+1}$. Thus $f^{-1}(0)$ is not a submanifold.

Comment: Your argument for why this isn't a submanifold at zero doesn't make any sense to me. If you think this is just because it is the inverse image of a critical value, then no, this does not prove $f^{-1}(0)$ is not a submanifold. For instance clearly $f(x,y)=x^3$ has singular derivative but $f^{-1}(0)$ is clearly a submanifold. This is at least the second consecutive question in dt. where you have posted an answer where the argument fails in very basic examples. Please be more careful next time, or post in subjects that you know better.